# How to make API function call inside ng-repeat?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, pug

I have a scope function defined in my controller which is calling an API to fetch data from database. I am using this scope function inside ng-repeat. But when I run the application, it is getting hanged, I know little bit about dirty checking, but I am not able to find how to handle such situation.

In my controler:

```
$scope.GetTranslatedText = function (categoryID, categoryDetailID, languageID) {
        $http.get('api/datacategorydetailtranslations' + '/' + categoryID + '/' + categoryDetailID + '/' + languageID).
        success(function (data) {
            return data.datacategorydetailtranslations;
        });
    };
```

Inside Index.jade

```
li(ng-repeat="property in properties track by property.PropertyID | orderBy : 'Region'" ng-init="abc=compute()" menuhover itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Hotel")
  a(ng-href='{{property.UrlName}}')
      img.hotelImage(ng-src='http://cdn.objects.florahospitality.com/media/property/thumbnail/{{property.PropertyThumbnail}}' alt="{{property.PropertyName}}" style="height:36px;width:40px;")
          div.column2
              p.hotelName(itemprop="name") {{property.PropertyName}}
                  div.thumbsUpNav(florapopover template="thumbsUpNav")
                      span.sprite_image.white_thumbs_up_icon
                  p.starRating
                      span(class="{{property.StarRating}}")                                                    
                          span(ng-show="property.Visible", style="width:310px;") {{property.StarRating}}
                  p.hotelAddress
                      span(itemprop="location") {{GetTranslatedText(2, property.StreetAddress, 1)}}
                      span.viewMap(data-item="4" itemprop="geo" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/GeoCoordinates") (Show Map)
                          meta(itemprop="latitude" content="25.2530800688814")
                          meta(itemprop="latitude" content="55.3282535076141")
```

Comment: Where do you need to call your api? PS: If you are looking for translation function, angular has a library for that. Thay may make your life easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you place a function inside of view interpolation, it gets evaluated at least twice *every digest cycle*, which can be many times per second. As such, it is not a good idea to put an API call into one of these functions.

Consider using a directive instead. Something like:

```
.directive('getTranslatedText', function($http){
  return {
    scope: {
      categoryID: '@catId',
      categoryDetailID: '@catDetailId',
      languageID: '@langId'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      $http.get('api/datacategorydetailtranslations' + '/' + scope.categoryID + '/' + scope.categoryDetailID + '/' + scope.languageID)
      .success(function (data) {
        scope.translated = data.datacategorydetailtranslations;
      });
    },
    template: '<span itemprop="location">{{translated}}</span>'
  }
});
```

... which would appear in your view looking something like this:

```
<span get-translated-text cat-id="2" cat-detail-id="{{property.StreetAddress}}"
lang-id="1"></span>
```

The API call would only run once per directive instance, at the point when its linking function is called.

[Here is a demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/6gSs1ROBFa44779Nb6tm?p=preview), which exhibits the concept but doesn't fully work as a result of the network request being invalid.

As an aside, `$http` calls are better contained inside of services, which other Angular components may call rather than in a controller or directive. I included it in the directive here, however, just to avoid introducing too many moving parts in my answer.

Comment: Thanks Marc :) You almost saved me. I was struggling for this from last couple of days but was not able to find any solution on net. Thanks a lot.